# How do I insert rows in a dataframe based on sequence?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have this dataframe. The columns 'Time' follows a sequence where there are all weeks that fall between the first and the last rows populated in the column. But one of the values i.e. W43-2021 is missing.

[image: Given DF]

How do I insert a new row corresponding to W43-2021 with all the other column values be either same as others or None and 'Values' as 0. Basically like the below dataframe.

[image: New DF]

I have tried tried below approach to solve this problem.

```
f = int(df['Time.[Week]'][0][1:3])
l = int(df['Time.[Week]'].iloc[-1][1:3])
check = list(df['Time.[Week]'].str[1:3])
check = list(map(int, check))
c = []
for i in range(f, l+1):
    if i not in check:
        c.append(i)
for week in c:
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns)

    temp_df.loc[0, 'Time.[Week]'] = 'W' + str(week) + '-2021'

df.append(temp_df)
```

This doesn't seem to be the most appropriate way of dealing with the issue as order is getting broken due to appending dataframe at the end and there could be multiple missing rows which could problem later.
What could be a better and more pythonic way of handling this case?

Also find the code to initiate the df if required.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[33534,9132,'Current','W41-2021',34],
              [33534,9132,'Current','W42-2021', 45],
              [33534,9132,'Current','W44-2021', 32],
              [33534,9132,'Current','W45-2021', 41],
              [33534,9132,'Current','W46-2021',49]], columns = ['Item', 'Location', 'Version', 'Time', 'Value'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
# build missing values
weeks = df['Time'].str.extract('(?<=W)(\d+)').astype(int)
idx = [f'W{w}-2021' for w in range(weeks.min()[0], weeks.max()[0]+1)]

# add missing values
df2 = df.set_index('Time').reindex(idx).reset_index()

# ffill, except 'Value'
df2 = df2.combine_first(df2.drop(columns='Value').ffill())[df.columns]
```

output:

```
>>> df2
      Item  Location  Version      Time  Value
0  33534.0    9132.0  Current  W41-2021   34.0
1  33534.0    9132.0  Current  W42-2021   45.0
2  33534.0    9132.0  Current  W43-2021    NaN
3  33534.0    9132.0  Current  W44-2021   32.0
4  33534.0    9132.0  Current  W45-2021   41.0
5  33534.0    9132.0  Current  W46-2021   49.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use -

```
df['week'] = df['Time'].str[1:3].astype(int)
df2 = pd.DataFrame([ i for i in range(week.min(), week.max())], columns=['week']).merge(df, how='outer')
fill_val = df['Time'].iloc[0]
df2['Time'] = df2['Time'].fillna(fill_val[0]+df2['week'].astype(str)+fill_val[3:])
df2 = df2.fillna(0)
```

**Output**

```
   week      Time  Value
0    41  W41-2021   34.0
1    42  W42-2021   45.0
2    43  W43-2021    0.0
3    44  W44-2021   32.0
4    45  W45-2021   41.0
5    46  W46-2021   49.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like that:

**Code:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[33534,9132,'Current','W41-2021',34],
              [33534,9132,'Current','W42-2021', 45],
              [33534,9132,'Current','W44-2021', 32],
              [33534,9132,'Current','W45-2021', 41],
              [33534,9132,'Current','W46-2021',49]], columns = ['Item', 'Location', 'Version', 'Time', 'Value'])

new_df = df.copy(deep=True)
new_df = new_df.append(pd.DataFrame([[33534,9132,'Current','W43-2021',0]],columns=['Item', 'Location', 'Version', 'Time', 'Value']))
new_df = new_df.sort_values("Time",ascending=True)
print(new_df)
```

Because the time is ordered you can just append the new value and then sort the values according to the time.

**Output:**

```
    Item  Location  Version      Time  Value
0  33534      9132  Current  W41-2021     34
1  33534      9132  Current  W42-2021     45
0  33534      9132  Current  W43-2021      0
2  33534      9132  Current  W44-2021     32
3  33534      9132  Current  W45-2021     41
4  33534      9132  Current  W46-2021     49
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1** with `merge()` process any years with actual number of weeks, NOT keep the column type (integer becomes float)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[33534, 9132, 'Current', 'W41-2021', 34],
                   [33534, 9132, 'Current', 'W42-2021', 45],
                   [33534, 9132, 'Current', 'W44-2021', 32],
                   [33534, 9132, 'Current', 'W45-2021', 41],
                   [33535, 5555, 'Current', 'W44-2022', 132],
                   [33535, 5555, 'Current', 'W45-2022', 141],
                   [33534, 9132, 'Current', 'W46-2021', 49]], columns=['Item', 'Location', 'Version', 'Time', 'Value'])

def yproc(gd):
    year = gd.Time.iloc[0].split('-')[1] # get the year from the group
    # compose a complete sequence like WNN-YYYY from all week numbers in a particular year
    ts = pd.Series([f'W{x+1:02d}-{year}' for x in pd.Series(pd.date_range(f'{year}-01-01',f'{year}-12-31',freq='W')).index],name='Time')
    d = gd.merge(ts, how='outer').sort_values('Time') # merge the df with the sequence
    d['Value'].fillna(0, inplace=True) # fill the values in the added rows
    return d.fillna(method='ffill').fillna(method='bfill') # fill other fields and return

y = df.Time.str.split('-', expand=True)[1] # make a sequence to group by year
df1 = df1 = df.groupby(y, as_index=False, group_keys=False).apply(yproc)  # grop by year and apply the function
print(df1.iloc[40:60,:])
```

Output:

```
       Item  Location  Version      Time  Value
0   33534.0    9132.0  Current  W41-2021   34.0
1   33534.0    9132.0  Current  W42-2021   45.0
45  33534.0    9132.0  Current  W43-2021    0.0
2   33534.0    9132.0  Current  W44-2021   32.0
3   33534.0    9132.0  Current  W45-2021   41.0
4   33534.0    9132.0  Current  W46-2021   49.0
46  33534.0    9132.0  Current  W47-2021    0.0
47  33534.0    9132.0  Current  W48-2021    0.0
48  33534.0    9132.0  Current  W49-2021    0.0
49  33534.0    9132.0  Current  W50-2021    0.0
50  33534.0    9132.0  Current  W51-2021    0.0
51  33534.0    9132.0  Current  W52-2021    0.0
2   33535.0    5555.0  Current  W01-2022    0.0
3   33535.0    5555.0  Current  W02-2022    0.0
4   33535.0    5555.0  Current  W03-2022    0.0
5   33535.0    5555.0  Current  W04-2022    0.0
6   33535.0    5555.0  Current  W05-2022    0.0
7   33535.0    5555.0  Current  W06-2022    0.0
8   33535.0    5555.0  Current  W07-2022    0.0
9   33535.0    5555.0  Current  W08-2022    0.0
```

**Option 2** with `concat()` process any years with actual number of weeks, keep the column type (i.e. integer)

```
# df = ...

def yproc(gd):
    year = gd.Time.iloc[0].split('-')[1]  # get the year from the group
    # compose a complete sequence like WNN-YYYY from all actual week numbers in a particular year
    ts = pd.Series(
        [f'W{x + 1:02d}-{year}' for x in range(pd.date_range(f'{year}-01-01', f'{year}-12-31', freq='W').size)],
        name='Time')
    repeated = pd.concat([gd.take([0])] * ts.size, ignore_index=True) # replicate one row nth times depend of weeks number
    repeated.Value, repeated.Time = 0, ts # replace Value with 0, Time with ts
    d = pd.concat([gd, repeated]).drop_duplicates(['Time'], keep='first').sort_values('Time')
    return d


y = df.Time.str.split('-', expand=True)[1]  # make a sequence to group by year
df1 = df.groupby(y, as_index=False, group_keys=False).apply(yproc)  # grop by year and apply the function
print(df1.iloc[39:60, :])
```

```
     Item  Location  Version      Time  Value
39  33534      9132  Current  W40-2021      0
0   33534      9132  Current  W41-2021     34
1   33534      9132  Current  W42-2021     45
42  33534      9132  Current  W43-2021      0
2   33534      9132  Current  W44-2021     32
3   33534      9132  Current  W45-2021     41
6   33534      9132  Current  W46-2021     49
46  33534      9132  Current  W47-2021      0
...
```